# How to make Example code more DRY?

Tags: django

I have the following code:

```
  for e in Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=batch.user, group=batch.group):
            msg = Message.objects.create(
                recipient_number=e.mobile,
            )
```

However, I want to do something like the below where first I check if the object has a `group` if not filter on `contact` instead else filter on group.

As you can see this is not very DRY. How can this be made better?

```
 if self.group == None:
        for e in Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=batch.user, contact=batch.group):
        msg = Message.objects.create(
            recipient_number=e.mobile,
        )

 else:
     for e in Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=batch.user, group=batch.group):
     msg = Message.objects.create(
        recipient_number=e.mobile,
     )
```

Comment: Both your code blocks are doing the same thing, so why do you have the if check?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it differs in what parameters he filters on.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid filters on contact=batch.group the other is group=batch.group everything else is the same.

Comment: Did you try chaining filters?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea you should consider in your case is taken from

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long, and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated

This allows you to build queries brick by brick.

```
 q = Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=batch.user)
 if self.group == None:
      q = q.filter(contact=batch.group)
 else
      q = q.filter(group=batch.group)

 for e in q:
    msg = Message.objects.create(
        recipient_number=e.mobile,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the if operator, if you prefer this kind of shorter writing

```
q=Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=batch.user)
q = q.filter(contact=batch.group) if self.group is None else q.filter(group=batch.group)
for e in q:
    msg = Message.objects.create(
        recipient_number=e.mobile,
    )
```